# Replace specific attribute label text on WooCommerce variable product pages

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, product

Is it possible to change label text on "Size" and "Color" product attributes to something else on WooCommerce single variable product pages?

I tried this css code:

```
.single-product table.variations td.label > label{
visibility: hidden;
}
.single-product table.variations td.label > label:after {
content: 'NEW NAME';
visibility: visible;
}
```

But it changes both “color” and “Size” Variations.
How do I separate them?

The label I want to change is `pa_farge` :

[Source code “Chrome Developer”](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFk1W.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**2021 Update**

Instead you can use the following WooCommerce dedicated filter hook to target a specific product attribute and changing its displayed label name as follows:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute_label', 'custom_attribute_label', 10, 3 );
function custom_attribute_label( $label, $name, $product ) {
    // For "pa_farge" attribute taxonomy on single product pages.
    if( $name == 'pa_farge' && is_product() ) {
        $label = __('NEW NAME', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $label;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Thank you for reply :) Is it possible to use a css code? I don’t have access to functions.php and can only input custom css in the theme.

Comment: Is this solution still working? I've tried it with a Colors attribute (pa_colors) but the label didn't change. Maybe last WooCommerce updates changed something?

Comment: @Marco Just updated the code… tested and works on last woocommerce version.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec yep! Now it works like a charm. Thank you!